# Image with correct directory not appearing on webpage

Tags: html, css, image

Please note, I'm new to HTML and have little to no knowledge of CSS.

I downloaded an [HTML/CSS](http://firefreebies.com/other-stuff/testimonial-htmlcss-sources/) file for a testimonial page of my website.

So far I've removed the grey background color from the CSS without a problem. However, when I wanted to change the default image of the person

```
<img src="img/photo.jpg" alt="" class="photo" />
```

to a testing image that I have used in other parts of my website (the file directory is correct)

```
<img src="Images/portfolioimage2.png" alt="" class="photo" />
```

The result removed the default person image but does not insert my image.

I'm almost possitive the issue is within the CSS as I pasted code from a different page using the same image onto the HTML page that comes with the download; and the image still does not load, even though the same image with the same line of code loads on another webpage with no CSS attached.

I'm using both the default CSS and HTML files that come with the download I linked to above. The only thing I have changed is that I removed the background color from the CSS and I changed 1 line in the HTML as highlighted above.

Any help is appreciated.

CSS as requested:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, 
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-      size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align: baseline;}
 /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
 footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {display: block;}
 body {line-height: 1;}
 ol, ul {list-style: none;list-style-position:outside;}
 blockquote, q {quotes: none;}
 blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
 q:before, q:after {content: '';content: none;}
 table {border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing:0;}

 body{font-family:Georgia,sans-serif;font-size:15px;}
 #block{width:506px;padding:230px 6px 0 6px;margin:0 auto;}
 #block h3{background:url(img/h3.png) no-repeat center;color:#dd3c04;font-     size:13px;font-weight:normal;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom:17px;}
 #block .photo{background:url(img/photo-bg.png) no-repeat center;margin-    right:6px;position:relative;float:left;}
 #block .photo img{max-width:115px;max-  height:115px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;}
 #block .photo img.photo-bg{z-index:1;}
 #block .photo img.photo{left:0;}
 #block p.content{font-style:italic;line-height:24px;padding-  left:19px;margin-left:121px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
 #block p.content span {text-indent;}
 #block p.content span.laquo{background:url(img/laquo.png) no-repeat;width:14px;height:11px;position:absolute;left:0;top:4px;display:block;}
 #block p.content span.raquo{background:url(img/raquo.png) no-repeat right 4px;width:13px;height:15px;padding-left:4px;display:inline-block;}
 #block .sign{text-align:right;float:right;}
 #block .sign a{color:#577302;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;}
 #block .sign a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
 #block .sign p{color:#5a5a5a;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;margin-top:6px;}
```

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Index</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<img src="Images/portfolioimage2.png" alt="" class="photo" />
<img src="Images/portfolioimage2.png" alt="" width="165" height="180">  
<!--testimonial 1 -->
<div id="block">
    <h3>Featured testimonial</h3>
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="img/photo-bg.png" alt="" class="photo-bg"/>
        <img src="Images/portfolioimage2.png" alt="" class="photo" />
    </div>
    <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sanctus corrumpit ei quo, eu quo meis brute, sed ut possit vocibus graecis. Dicant mandamus ne duo, mazim aperiam ei eos.<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <div class="sign">
        <a href="#">Jay Hafling</a>
        <p>Freelance web-designer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the CSS file?

Comment: `.photo{background:url(img/photo-bg.png) ` the problem may be here. change this path and try again.

Comment: Are you sure your path is "Images" not "images" ?

Comment: I'll add the HTML as well.

Comment: Your HTML and CSS works fine in my computer when *Images/portfolioimage2.png* is there. Are you sure the *Images* directory is in the same directory as the *index.html*?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code preventing a custom image replacing the one that comes with the template. It works fine in my PC.

The only possibility is the path. Please copy your image inside the existing "img" directory and replce only the file name. This should solve your problem.

```
<img src="img/portfolioimage2.png" alt="" class="photo" />
```